# Retrieving common Classes' attributes from DBPedia with SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to retrieve some properties for certain classes in dbpedia. Consider you have a country. It does exist in the ontology but I want to retrieve some related common properties, like name, currency, time zone, etc. But there is no such information in http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country.

```
SELECT *                
WHERE {                        
  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country> ?predicate ?object.         
}
```

And it is logic. The query just return 15 matchings, and even wikipedia does not have such information (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country ). But if you enter a concrete country, lets say Brasil, you can see such information in Wikipedia. And here I have two problems:

1) I can't access such data from dbpedia. I tryed:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Brasil> ?prop ?label.
}
```

2) I need the common properties of most of the countries. In fact, what I need are the properties of the class, not the values of the instances. E.g. I don't need to retrieve "Brasil", "Uruguay" or "Argentina", but "name". I don't need to retrieve "Real", "Uruguayan peso" or "Peso", but "Currency".

Any clue where I should look?

Comment: Properties are not related to classes but used by instances, that's why your query doesn't return any result. The answer below shows the way how it's done usually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you really want is all of the instances of Country, so the initial query would be:

```
SELECT ?country
WHERE {
    ?country a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country>
}
```

To get the common properties for Countries in DBPedia, try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p
WHERE {
    ?country a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country> .
    ?country ?p ?o .
}
```