# Finding properties that are common to a class in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have a question on how to find distinct properties for instances that share a class in DBpedia. I think it is more on the lines of how to do it in SPARQL. I tried out this query here :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p WHERE {
       ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film> .
       ?s ?p ?o.
}
```

However, I realized that this query gives you all the distinct properties that are used by all instances, essentially while the distinct properties for the instance of a class might remain just the same i.e. in [LUBM](http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/projects/lubm/) for example, in a real life Wikipedia based extraction set like DBpedia, you don't have that. So a count on the query above would give me `1767 distinct properties`. But how do you find all the properties that are common to the instance of a class in SPARQL? As in, a set of properties that occur for the instance of a class and are common for an entire set. This should be a smaller set than the 1767 right? Again for LUBM the above query does it and seems like all the instances share the same set of distinct properties. I guess for DBpedia that wouldn't be the case. I also know that this can be done in Java for example. I could just iterate through all the properties for all the instances of the class and just save the ones that appear in all. I think that is too expensive,and was wondering if it is possible in SPARQL.

PS: Somebody sort of asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446323/retrieving-common-classes-attributes-from-dbpedia-with-sparql/35447231), but as I have written here, I am not sure if that actually captures the common properties to all classes.

Comment: Please confirm — you want to get a list of all the properties for which every instance of a class has a value in the DBpedia dataset?  So if any `dbo:Film` description does not include a `dbo:costumeDesigner` (whether or not it actually had one), you don't want that property included?

Comment: So lets say I had to describe a Film just using DBpedia, my first way to do that would be to actually look at all instances of a Film. Then I'd say, oh! all instances of the Film have 'n' properties. My initial hunch was that all the instances share the same property set. However, in practice and theory as well, it can't be true. An instance could have other properties and so on. So the question becomes "What properties of instances of a class are common among all the instances of the class", as in what properties actually have a value (datatype or object type) for all instances of the class.

Comment: I don't think your goal is clear... Getting a film's description *from* DBpedia (which is derived from Wikipedia) is not the same as creating a film description *for* DBpedia (which should be done by describing it on Wikipedia)...

Comment: Yes I do know that. I am only interested in how the properties of an class are distributed in DBpedia and maybe any other dataset. I am using DBpedia as a reference. However it could just be any other RDF Dataset. Maybe somebody else defined Film from LinkedMDB for example.  Even then I'd want to know that for a particular class (in this example Film) how are the properties distributed and which ones are common to all instances, (obviously if this is mentioned in the owl file as rdfs:domain or rdfs:range) I'll not look further, but in practice that is not the case and hence this query.

Comment: Hmm. A Class (e.g., `dbo:Film`) is described by listing all Properties which *might* apply to all instances. Not all Properties have (known) values — but they still apply. [Star Wars](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Star_Wars) has many more *known* property values than [The Pest](http://dbpedia.org/page/The_Pest_%281922_film%29) — but many more property values *exist* for the latter than are known (by DBpedia)… Maybe you're actually looking for common properties which are external to the Class definition? I'm really not understanding your goal…

Comment: Lets say we have two Classes dbo:Film and b:Film. Now lets say that dbo:Film has properties {director,academyAward,writtenBy} . So I'd like to know how many instances of dbo:Film have all the properties {director,academyAward,writtenBy} . If that doesn't exist, which instances have a subset of these properties, but all of them should have it. I have framed it as "Which properties are common to all instances". It could just be rdf:type as seen from @JoshuaTaylor's query or maybe more than that too. So now I'd look for fraction of properties shared by most instances.

Comment: In theory, an ontological definition of a Class would list all characteristics (attributes, predicates) of any instance of that Class. Some would say that every instance of the Class should have every attribute — but even in that case, any given *description* of that instance might not have a value for every attribute which that *instance* has. In practice, RDF data sets tend to have a lot of these unstated values. You talked about about two Classes, but you only dug into the instance data for `dbo:Film`, so I still don't know what this has to do with `b:Film`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for properties such that every Film has a value for those properties, then you could express that with a query like:

```sql
select distinct ?p {
  #-- Find all the distinct properties 
  #-- of some reference Film.  It shouldn't
  #-- matter which Film we get.
  { select distinct ?p { 
    { select ?ex { ?ex a dbo:Film } limit 1 }

    ?ex ?p ?o
    }
  }

  #-- Now exclude any of those properties
  #-- if there is a Film that doesn't have
  #-- a value for them.
  filter not exists {
    ?f a dbo:Film .
    filter not exists { ?f ?p ?o }
  }
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fp%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20Find%20all%20the%20distinct%20properties%20%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20of%20some%20reference%20Film.%20%20It%20shouldn%27t%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20matter%20which%20Film%20we%20get.%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20select%20distinct%20%3Fp%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20select%20%3Fex%20%7B%20%3Fex%20a%20dbo%3AFilm%20%7D%20limit%201%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fex%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20Now%20exclude%20any%20of%20those%20properties%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20if%20there%20is%20a%20Film%20that%20doesn%27t%20have%0D%0A%20%20%23--%20a%20value%20for%20them.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ff%20a%20dbo%3AFilm%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20filter%20not%20exists%20%7B%20%3Ff%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

This query finds a single film and then gets all of its distinct properties.  Since we're looking for properties that *all* Films have, it doesn't matter which film we choose as the single one.  Then we filter out any of those properties where some Film *doesn't* have a property for them.  What's left is exactly those properties that every Film has.

Unfortunately, it seems like the only property that *every* Film in the DBpedia data has is **rdf:type**.

Comment: Thank you so much @JoshuaTaylor! That is quite surprising to be honest. However I'll have to work with that I guess. Obviously I'd have to again work on the query to look at properties that are shared the most among all instances. I'd assume that the same is not true for all RDF data right? One should in theory have a set that is > 1 (for sure) right?.

Comment: @N00bsie Because of the way the query is structured (finding things that have a particular value for the **rdf:type** property), you're guaranteed that they'll all have at least property in common: **rdf:type**.  Aside from that, I don't know of any a priori reason to expect that an arbitrary set of resources has some larger set of common properties.

Comment: @N00bsie I was actually surprised by the DBpedia results though.  I'd have though that there would be, e.g., an rdfs:label on all the Films, but it turns out that some of the Films don't correspond to Wikipedia artcles.  E.g., try **select ?f where { ?f a dbo:Film filter not exists { ?f rdfs:label ?label } }**.

Comment: You should not be surprised that there is no property from the DBpedia ontology used by all films. The dataset is indeed incomplete. We already did such an analysis in DBpedia and used a lot's of complex SPARQL queries that comüute those statistics for each class and property.

Comment: @AKSW would it be possible to share the statistics and/or queries or if it is already there, then a pointer to it? For example, is there any other property set that all the Actors share, all the Directors share and so on.

Comment: @AKSW What was surprising to me is that not all films correspond to Wikipedia articles.  My impression is that every individual that **does** correspond to a Wikipedia article would have an rdfs:label (the name of the article), and abstract, etc.  So for some classes, I bet there is a larger set of common properties.

Comment: True @JoshuaTaylor. I tried your query  on other classes for example Athlete, or Actor or Person. Now Person is the super class for a lot of other classes. So is Athlete, all of them seem to have only one common property, which is rdf:type. Now I'd expect properties like givenName to be there as well.

Comment: @N00bsie Be sure to run a query to find some of the instances that *don't* have a property that you'd expect.  You'll probably figure out why the exceptions are there.  And remember that those properties are based on the infoboxes used on DBpedia.  So it only takes one stub article without much data to get an individual that doesn't have all the properties you might expect.  Or wiki disambiguation pages, deleted articles, etc.

Comment: E.g., look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigers_FC_(Cayman_Islands) -- the players listed there  end up listed as athletes, but since there is no article, there are no infoboxes to get first name, last name, label, etc., from.  It's actually kind of interesting, and reveals something interesting about the DBpedia information extraction process.  As I mentioned to @AKSW, what was surprising to me is that not all the entries have articles.  This helps to explain why.

Answer (score 2):

Dereferencing the Film URI will tell you everything you need to know about the Film class in DBpedia:

The HTML resource:

http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Film

The RDF resource:

http://dbpedia.org/data3/Film.ttl

The SPARQL query for domain and range properties of the film:

```
SELECT ?predicate 
WHERE {
?predicate rdfs:domain|rdfs:range <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Film>
}
```

Comment: This might not provide the answer OP is looking for.  This will return properties that explicitly have the domain or range Film, but not necessarily properties whose domain or range are *subclasses* of Film (whose use would imply that the relevant instance is an instance of Film), or properties whose domain or range are *superclasses* of Film, which could be consistently be applied to Films as well.  OP's question makes it sound like what's desired is the set of properties for which all Films have a value.

Comment: Okay I must admit I tried that query first on my local instance before actually asking this on stackoverflow. However that gave me no results. On the public DBpedia, it did. So I guess that's got something to do with my Virtuoso instance. Coming back to the question. @JoshuaTaylor is right. This would give out properties that explicitly have the domain and range specified already. I am interested in the set of properties that is common to all instances or the set properties that all instances of Film have a value for.

Comment: @N00bsie I think that [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39414521/1281433) matches your specification.